# How can you detect if your activity is being onPaused because of a PendingIntent which you created?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, activity-lifecycle

If I have an Activity which is in the foreground and I navigate to another Activity within my app, I can detect this by setting a flag when you begin the transfer and wiping it when you have transferred to the new activity. This allows me to distinguish between an activity onPause due to an internal (flag set) or external (flag not set) event.

However, I am having trouble doing this for PendingIntents embedded in Notifications. Is it possible to detect that my Activity is being onPaused because they selected the notification I created on the notification bar? Is there some kind of notification listener I can use which will trigger **before** the notification fires and the pending intent is executed which onPauses my Activity?

I appreciate that this is somewhat confusing, so I've made a skeleton project which demonstrates the problem:

```
package com.example.notificationtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int INCOMING_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private static final String TAG = "NotificationTest";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.e(TAG,"onPause");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e(TAG,"onResume");
}

public void onTransitionButtonClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    Log.e(TAG,"About to start activity: onPause will be invoked.");
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onNotificationButtonClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    Notification notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame, "Alert!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Click to open", "Click to open", pendingIntent);

    // Show the alert.
    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(INCOMING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}

}
```

With the activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/notify_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text="Make a notification"
    android:onClick="onNotificationButtonClick"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notify_button"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text="Normal transition"
    android:onClick="onTransitionButtonClick"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you select the "Normal transition" button, the log prints "About to start activity: onPause will be invoked." prior to onPause.

If you select the "Make a notification" button and then drag down the notification bar and tap on the notification, I want to be informed of that tap prior to onPause so I can insert the same line "About to start activity: onPause will be invoked.". How can I do that?

Comment: Ach, there's no justice in this world.

Comment: Tal Kanel's answer was more thorough, complete with code snippets. Sorry :(

Comment: Yeah I know, and I spent five times as much time on this, inspiring you to refine your question. :) But of course, I should've come up with a sexier update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

beside holding intent to start activity, **`PendingIntent` can hold also intent to "fire" a broadcast**.

you can use such custom broadcast as trigger to the notification, then implement `BroadcastReceiver` that will be registered to that broadcast, and will show whatever you want , and only then will start the desired activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.custom.broadcast.action");
pendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

the receiver will look something like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //do whatever you want
        // if this code is being executed - it's a sign that the user clicked on the notification...

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Log.e(TAG,"About to start activity: onPause will be invoked.");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
};
```

don't forget to register the `mReceiver`  when `onCreate()` invokes, and unregister it `onDestroy()`

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver , new IntentFilter("my.custom.broadcast.action"));
unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```

in this approach you can control exactly what will happen when the user click on the notification. as you can see - it's possible only to send broadcast when notification clicked.  no one said you must start activity at all..

Answer (score 1):

Let me begin by trying to translate your question to another (just for clarity): *How can I have my Activity execute code before it is paused because an Activity associated with my Notification (which I can control) is going to be displayed?*

Provided that the translation is good enough for the purpose of answering:

Are you sure that this approach would be a solution? Because there are many cases where your Activity will get paused and the user displays your Notification's Activity "almost immediately after", while there will still be steps in between (like when other notifications are viewed first). I presume that technically, this means that you still must perform the same code there, while at the same time you can't have any indication that your notification will be viewed "in the very near future".

So for a suitable answer, I believe one will have to think outside of the box a bit, depending on the nature of the code you intend to execute and the motivation for it.

So if you update your question in this regard and notify me, I'll be glad to have a second look.

**Update after update of question:**

You can avoid firing the next Activity when the user presses the notification, and instead just fire an event. If your activity registers a BroadcastReceiver programmatically, it should be able to receive this event, and then update itself and start the next Activity, just as you wish.